# Failed to restart mongod.service : Unit mongod.service not found

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, bitnami

There are a lot of variations for this question, on different forums. I tried a lot of things to get it to work. I am using AWS EC2 and MEAN by Bitnami, I tried connecting using Node JS and I realized that my monogodb service is not running. I checked it by running on the terminal (connected using Putty)

```
service mongod status
```

This is the error I get

> mongodb.service Loaded:not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
>   Active: inactive(dead)

To try my luck, I tried

```
 sudo service mongod restart
```

And I get this error:

> Failed to restart mongod.service : Unit mongod.service not found

Now, just to probe more I tried looking if I have this service installed.
I ran this command: `ls /lib/systemd/system` 
And it gave a huge list, but I couldn't find mongod.service anywhere.

My Ubuntu Ver: 16.04 
I am guessing it's not present or maybe I am looking for the wrong stuff. Please let me know how do I get the service to run. I am sort of new to MongoDB and Bitnami.

Comment: How did you install mongodb? Unless you used the AMI package you wouldn’t have the systemd service created. Also your `service status` is wrong, it should be `service mongod status`

Comment: I used the default MEAN by Bitnami on AWS.  Please ignore the `service mongod status` it was a typo. sorry for that.  Do you think the service runs automatically ? I tried this command : `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh status mongodb` and it says mongodb already running. Now I am confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Bitnami MEAN stack includes a control script that lets you easily stop, start and restart services.

The script is located at `/opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh`.

To start all services:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start
```

To start a single service:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start <service name>
```

So to answer your question:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start mongod
```

You can obtain a list of available services and operations by running the script without any arguments:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh
```

Comment: Thank for the list, I did go through the bitnami documents and found out those. However my services are runnning , which i stopped and restarted using the same scripts. But I am still not able to connect from my node JS, I get this error :  **MongoError: failed to connect to server [admin:27017] on first connect [MongoError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND admin admin:27017]** I am not sure where what I missed

Comment: @Arun- my answer is a fix for you OP.

Comment: @Arun- if you can create a new question with all the details of your nodeJs and error.  At first glance it seems to be picking up your host name as `admin` but would need to see your code to help