# MongoError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND admin admin:27017

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, bitnami

I am getting this error when I try to connect using Node JS. My setup is as follows:

- AWS EC 2
- MEAN by Bitnami

My Server.js

```
// set up ======================================================================
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var mongoose = require('mongoose');                 // mongoose for mongodb
var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;                // set the port
var database = require('./config/database');            // load the database config
var morgan = require('morgan');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var messageId = {};

// configuration ===============================================================
//mongoose.connect(database.localUrl);  // Connect to local MongoDB instance. A remoteUrl is also available (modulus.io)

//app.use(express.static('./public'));      // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
//app.use(morgan('dev')); // log every request to the console
//app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended': 'true'})); // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
//app.use(bodyParser.json()); // parse application/json
//app.use(bodyParser.json({type: 'application/vnd.api+json'})); // parse application/vnd.api+json as json
//app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override')); // override with the X-HTTP-Method-Override header in the request
// Connect to  Mongo DB
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
mongoose.connect(database.remoteUrl)
mongoose.connection.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('Could not connect to the database. Exiting now...',e);
    process.exit();
});
mongoose.connection.once('open', function() { 
    console.log("Successfully connected to the database");
})
io.set('origins', '*:*');
http = require('http'),
server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    //res.writeHead(200,{'content-type':'text/plain'});
    //  res.write("Sever On");
    // res.end();
}),
io = io.listen(server);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('User Connected -- Server Online');   
    socket.on('message', function (msg,msgId) {
        io.emit('message', "Hello");
        console.log("message from client:", msg);
         setInterval(function(){
          io.emit("messageStatus",msgId);
      },500)
   });
});
// app.get('/', function (req, res) {
//     res.send('hello world')
// })
server.listen(port);
console.log("App listening on port " + port);
```

This is my database.js

```
module.exports = {
    remoteUrl : 'mongodb://username:password@mysystem@ec2-22-22-22.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:27017/testdb'      
};
```

I have made sure that my Mongo DB is running by checking it using this command:

> sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh status mongodb

And it says **mongodb already running**

Please let me know if I did something wrong, I am new with MongoDB and Node JS.

Answer (score 0):

I was connecting to the admin itself, I created another user on the same database and now it works fine. Thanks to  **[N3i1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9251303/n3i1)** to point it out in [another post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48711094/failed-to-restart-mongod-service-unit-mongod-service-not-found/48712270?noredirect=1#comment84423999_48712270)

Comment: glad you found the issue